# Vimtex commands only working on main file

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-vimtex

Hi I am trying out vimtex on a multi-file project, and so far I was liking it a lot. However, I just found out that vimtex commands (`\lv`, `\lt`, `\li`, etc) work correctly when used while editing the main file, but have no effect when editing imported files.

Now since most of the work happens in imported files this is quite a big problem. By the way, continuos compilation does not stop when switching to imported files, so I can still see changes in real-time.

I am on ubuntu, using vim 8.0 compiled with `--with-features=huge` and using zathura for pdf visualization.

I have tried creating an empty `main.tex.latexmain` file and also putting all the imported files in the same folder of main file.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Are the filetypes being set correctly? Thats my first thought if the mappings arent working.

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble I'm not sure I know what you are referring to. I have some .tex files in a folder and I import them in the main.tex. Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: Check the output of `set filetype` (i think) when you have the imported files open, and then check the output of `map` if the filetype is correctly set to tex or latex.

Comment: You probably need to add `let g:tex_flavor = 'latex'`.

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble Checked the filetype and it was `tex`, strangely `map`actually showed the correct mapping but they did not work.

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg Thank you! That worked perfectly. If you post it as an answer I will accept it. Could you please also add a line explaining what was the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: add `let g:tex_flavor = 'latex'` to your vimrc file.

---

So, more details. First: This problem is not related to [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex). vimtex depends on the internal `tex` plugin, e.g. for filetype detection and syntax, and this particular problem is with how the internal `tex` plugin recognizes the filetype.

To be more specific, the internal `tex` plugin differs between different flavors: `plain`, `context`, and `latex`. Which one is used depends on two things:

1. The header of the loaded file, and
2. The value of the `g:tex_flavor` option.

The `g:tex_flavor` option is used to set the "default" style, which is used when the flavor can not be decided from the header. The header is parsed for two things: Either a `%&<format>` string, or some keywords that identify the flavor. If you don't set `g:tex_flavor`, it defaults to `plaintex`.

For more details, see:

- `:h g:tex_flavor`
- [`:e $VIMRUNTIME/autoload/dist/ft.vim` (close to line 636)](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/autoload/dist/ft.vim#L636) (different location in neovim)